# Expected 1 argument, but got 0 in angular

Tags: angular, tsconfig

When I run `ng build --prod`, I get this error: 
`node_modules/ngx-image-viewer/ngx-image-viewer.d.ts. Component: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0`.

I'm sure that there is something going wrong with tsconfig.app.json. So, I configured it by editing `types: ["node"]` to `types: []` in `compilerOptions`. But, then I get error: `ERROR in node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http_response.d.ts:1:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'`. So, there is no way of configuring `types: []` array. Because, either the way I'm getting error.

Here have a look of my tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

How can I avoid this error: `Expected 1 arguments, But got 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [ngx-image-viewer](https://github.com/jpilfold/ngx-image-viewer) did not upgrade itself to Angular 8. I Just took a glimpse at that repository and they have not touched the source for at least 2 years.

I am not familiar with `ngx-image-viewer` lib, but my guess is that error relates to a post-angular-8-definition of a `ViewChild` declaration.

you can fork the source, upgrade and rebuild it, or, downgrade your angular version.

Comment: Yeah. There is some configuration conflict. I changed ngx-image-viewer to angular-x-image-viewer. Now, it's working fine.